# 6700HQ Ubuntu install broken bios suspected/CPU lockup xx seconds

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, laptop

So I have tried to get Ubuntu to boot/install on my MSI Apache GE72 6QF.
After weeks of trying and searching on google I have found MY solution that I found on a high tech site documented.

When I tried to boot Ubuntu 15.04 (or any other version for that matter) I got either the

> Broken bios suspected

error, or

> CPU soft lockup 22 seconds

error.

No solution has worked so far for me, and I have tried them all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go into BIOS and DISABLE C-States, this means that your CPU will not be able to turn off when not in use, increasing power usage but fixing your issue.

If you do not have the C-States setting in your laptop, update your BIOS.

This working PERFECTLY for me, and I also found out that this will be fixed in the next few kernel updates.
I also read that it is a fault in the processor microcode (dont quote me on this though)

EDIT 07-04 It seems that 15.10 works as well, 15.10 also fixes the ACPI error which causes the PC to not shutdown properly in 15.04

Comment: This never made a difference in my case. For 16.04 I had to add kernel options `acpi_osi="Linux"` and `pci=nomsi`. Unfortunately, these options are not working for me after the 16.10, so I'm currently trying to troubleshoot because can't boot it... :/